# Can a Relay Module be powered by the GPIO pin or do I need DC adaptor?

Tags: relay

I have a 5 V 10 Amp relay module and a Raspberry Pi 3. I am using it to connect to a submersible pump which runs on AC power. Can I use the 5 V GPIO pin of the Raspberry Pi or do I need to buy a DC adaptor?

Comment: How much current does the spec sheet of this anonymous module say it needs?

Comment: It seems that there is another question regarding this topic
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34512/what-things-i-can-use-for-turning-on-a-relay?rq=1

Comment: The module is rated 5 V 10 Amperes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What things I can use for turning on a relay?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34512/what-things-i-can-use-for-turning-on-a-relay)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28201/9749) might help.  You should stay away from the RPi with relais and so on from a power point of view.  The RPi is not made to provide power for those devices.  The RPi is only capable of controlling them the way I describe in the above mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have a clear understanding of what's going on. Or perhaps I can't read what you wrote.

You need an AC->DC converter. This is not negotiable. Whatever you give power to the Pi through the USB or the +5V pin changes little. Decent industrial 220VAC -> 5VDC converters for this power can be as little as 10 bucks. 220VAC to pi = BOOM.

You will need a supporting relay board.